# Randomly getting capped collection error in tests

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

**===EDIT===**

Before editing the contents, let me tell you that this question is the exact duplicate of [Trying to create a mongodb collection in grails using mongodb plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748788/trying-to-create-a-mongodb-collection-in-grails-using-mongodb-plugin). However, the solution given doesn't work for me, and the context in which I am working may be different. So, this question.

**==========**

I am getting the following capped collections related error while running tests for capped collections over mongo. Following are the version of softwares that I am using:

1. Grails 2.1.2
2. MongoDB 2.4.0
3. Java 1.6.0.45
4. Groovy 1.8.8
5. Mongo Java Driver 2.12.3

**====EDIT=====**

I have a class `CappedCollectionCreator` as follows:

```
class CappedCollectionCreator {

    public void createCappedPublishedCollection(DBApiLayer db, String publishedCollectionName, String archiveCollectionName, int size, int max) {

        if (db.collectionExists(publishedCollectionName)) {
            def publishedCollection = db.getCollection(publishedCollectionName)

            if (!publishedCollection.getStats().get("capped")) {

                if (!db.collectionExists(archiveCollectionName)) {
                    def documents = publishedCollection.find().toArray()
                    if (documents.size() > 0) {
                        def archiveCollection = db.createCollection(archiveCollectionName, null)
                        archiveCollection.insert(publishedCollection.find().toArray())
                    }
                }

                def firstDocumentInserted = publishedCollection.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("createdOn", 1)).limit(1).toArray()
                publishedCollection.drop()
                db.createCollection(publishedCollectionName, BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("capped", true).add("size", size).add("max", max).get())
                publishedCollection = db.getCollection(publishedCollectionName)
                publishedCollection.insert(firstDocumentInserted)

            }
        } else {
            db.createCollection(publishedCollectionName, BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("capped", true).add("size", size).add("max", max).get())
        }
    }
}
```

The code that I am having problem with is in the following snippet:

```
@TestMixin(GroovyTestCase)
class CappedCollectionCreatorTests {

    def mongo
    def db
    def mongoCollectionProcessor
    def collectionName = "cappedCollectionTest"
    def archiveName = "cappedCollectionTestArchive"
    def collection, archiveCollection

    @Before
    void setUp() {

        mongo = mongo.getMongo()
        db = mongo.getDB("test")
        mongoCollectionProcessor = new CappedCollectionCreator()


        if (db.collectionExists(collectionName)) {
            collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
            collection.drop();
        }

        if (db.collectionExists(archiveName)) {
            archiveCollection = db.getCollection(archiveName);
            archiveCollection.drop();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldCreateCappedCollectionWhenDoesNotExist() {

        mongoCollectionProcessor.createCappedPublishedCollection(db, collectionName, archiveName, 1000, 1)

        assert db.collectionExists(collectionName) == true
        assert db.collectionExists(archiveName) == false
        assert db.getCollection(collectionName).isCapped() == true
}
```

}

**==========**

I searched over the Internet and **tried** most of the first searches such as **using DBObject and Map interchageably, casting DBObject to Map, etc.** But none seems to work.

```
| Running 339 integration tests... 245 of 339
| Running 339 integration tests... 246 of 339
| Failure:  testShouldCreateCappedCollectionWhenDoesNotExist(uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests)
|  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.mongodb.DBApiLayer#createCollection.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.String, class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class java.lang.String, interface com.mongodb.DBObject]
[class java.lang.String, interface java.util.Map]
at uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreator.createCappedPublishedCollection(CappedCollectionCreator.groovy:34)
at uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests.testShouldCreateCappedCollectionWhenDoesNotExist(CappedCollectionCreatorTests.groovy:43)
| Running 339 integration tests... 247 of 339
| Failure:  testShouldNotCreateCappedCollectionWhenExists(uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests)
|  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.mongodb.DBApiLayer#createCollection.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.String, class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class java.lang.String, interface com.mongodb.DBObject]
[class java.lang.String, interface java.util.Map]
at uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests.testShouldNotCreateCappedCollectionWhenExists(CappedCollectionCreatorTests.groovy:54)
| Running 339 integration tests... 248 of 339
| Failure:  testShouldCreateCappedCollectionAndArchiveWhenExistsNoCappedCollection(uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests)
|  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.mongodb.DBApiLayer#createCollection.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.String, null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class java.lang.String, interface com.mongodb.DBObject]
[class java.lang.String, interface java.util.Map]
at uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests.testShouldCreateCappedCollectionAndArchiveWhenExistsNoCappedCollection(CappedCollectionCreatorTests.groovy:70)
| Running 339 integration tests... 249 of 339
| Failure:  testShouldCreateCappedCollectionAndNoArchiveWhenExistsEmptyNoCappedCollection(uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests)
|  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.mongodb.DBApiLayer#createCollection.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.String, null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class java.lang.String, interface com.mongodb.DBObject]
[class java.lang.String, interface java.util.Map]
at uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests.testShouldCreateCappedCollectionAndNoArchiveWhenExistsEmptyNoCappedCollection(CappedCollectionCreatorTests.groovy:90)
| Running 339 integration tests... 250 of 339
| Failure:  testShouldCreateCappedCollectionAndNoArchiveWhenExistsNoCappedCollectionAndArchiveCollection(uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests)
|  groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.mongodb.DBApiLayer#createCollection.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.lang.String, null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
[class java.lang.String, interface com.mongodb.DBObject]
[class java.lang.String, interface java.util.Map]
at uk.co.o2.pm.manager.infrastructure.CappedCollectionCreatorTests.testShouldCreateCappedCollectionAndNoArchiveWhenExistsNoCappedCollectionAndArchiveCollection(CappedCollectionCreatorTests.groovy:103)
| Running 339 integration tests... 251 of 339
| Running 339 integration tests... 252 of 339
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Seems to be a problem with Mongo Groovy driver not being able to make out the method signature dynamically. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your test code where this is failing?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I understand how bad my question was presented in haste. Will take care next time. Please have a look now.

Comment: Have you tried giving it an empty DBObject or Map here instead of null: db.createCollection(archiveCollectionName, null) ?

Comment: Yes I have tried with empty DBObject, empty map as well